# ExtJS 5.0 - when overriding class, where can new resources go?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have production code which we are not allowed to modify, can use only overrides. I want to change the appearance, adding some images, etc. The code can go into `overrides`, no problem there, wondering where custom images and other resources can be located?

The original images have links like:

`src: 'resources/do-not-touch/images/logo.png'`,

which when combined with the home directory:

`build/production/App/`,

and the site:

`http://localhost:1841/`,

translates into:

`http://localhost:1841/build/production/App/resources/do-not-touch/images/logo.png`

Can I put resources into `overrides` somehow? Or should I bypass, and just link via `http://` to an absolute address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `overrides/` you can put a directory `resources/` and in there put whatever you need, e.g. `logo.png`. You would reference like this: `src: 'overrides/resources/logo.png'`. The last step is to modify `app.json` and add `"overrides/resources"` to the `"resources"` section. Build and everything should work. You're not touching anything in `do-not-touch/`, or even in `resources/`.

Answer (score 0):

You're working under some severely harsh constraints. If you absolutely can not put resources in their normal location, then they won't get packaged with the application properly. As such, your only real choice will be to use an absolute URL.

Overrides are used to alter the behaviour of JavaScript classes, not to provide arbitrary resources.

But the right answer is to change the problem, and be allowed to put the resources where they need to be. Presumably your application is being packaged normally so that the overrides can be included, after all.